# Measure parallel speedup in randomized-algorithms

Tags: parallel-processing, benchmarking, parallelism-amdahl

I have a randomized program with sequential and parallel variants. The nature of that program is that its run-time varies drastically depending on its "luck". It regularly takes values between 1sec and 2 min in a seemingly geomentric-distribution-ish pattern. Parallel variants show a similar behaviour with different numbers.

What is a "good" way measure parallel speedup in this case? 
I have the possibility to just use the mean/median of measured values as a representative for "the run-time"

How would I explain such an approach and is there a (statistically/mathematically) better way to calculate the speedup?

EDIT: Thanks to user3666197, which noted some very important technical details necessary to get good data. 
I have done that homework and want to clarify my question.

I made my benchmark process as reliable as I could get it:

- the benchmarks are run with seeds, with which the results are reproducible.
- every configuration is repeated multiple times (~400 times) with different seeds inside a script

My question remains: **How to approach the calculation of the speedup for this program.**

What I have done:

Mean sequential run-time is about 8.38, median is 4.8, which is a big difference. For 2 threads, mean run-time is 4.36 while median run-time is 2.42.
If I divide sequential by parallel I get speedups of 1.92 (means) and 1.992 (medians). 
For 4 threads similar: means: 2.25 run-time and 3.72 speedups, medians: 1.12 median and 4.3 speedup (superlinear).
Similar numbers exist for 8 threads.

I try to visualize the data in different ways. [Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7CjD.png)

The histogram shows the distribtion of run-times using various threads, as does the boxplot to its right. It is visible that *some* speedup is visible.

If I pair the measurements based on seeds, I get pairs of times: sequential and parallel times.
One of my first ideas was to calculate the speedup by calculating the slope of the regression-line, however, it seems that the regression-line does not properly "summarize" the data and has limited value. In the bottom-right plot, only the points for 4 threads are shown.

Comment: I measure the time by using the unix `/usr/bin/time` command. However, using any other metric would not change much: the program may get lucky to get to the solution quickly or may need more time to complete its task based on the seeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you compute the speedup based on the **arithmetic mean of runtimes of a sufficiently large set of measurements**. Make sure to properly communicate what the numbers represent. It can be difficult to ensure that you have a large enough set up measurements to compute a proper mean with a certain confidence, especially since your samples are not normally distributed. Include your findings about distribution and confindence. Make sure to summarize the runtimes first, before computing the speedup.

There is an excellent [paper by Torsten Hoefler and Roberto Belli](https://htor.inf.ethz.ch/publications/index.php?pub=222) which covers your issues in detail. Particularly Sections 2.1.1 and 3.

Comment: Is the **arithmetic mean** really the correct measurement? Notice that it is in my case around double the median. And other metrics return even other values. Which one is the "best" speedup-numer and why?

Comment: Think of it as transforming the question to the speedup for N executions. The total time for N executions. This time has a much more narrow distribution and is thus suitable for comparison and computing the speedup. The speedup for this compound operation is the same as if you compute it by the average runtimes. The median is much more problematic if the distribution differs for the serial/parallel case. There might be arguments for other metrics in special cases, but this is the most generic one. In any case, clearly describing the distribution and how the metric was computed is important.

Answer (score 0):

### How to measure a parallel-speedup versus a pure-`[SERIAL]` code?

Always be both quantitative and systematic.

That means at least:

1) use all systematic-steps for controlled test-repeatability
2) compare apples to apples, incl. the controlled seed-setup for randomizers
3) best, generate all test-batteries as scripted, auto-repeatable experiments
4) record the performance ( overall and local-sections timing ) in tests' UUID#-distinguishable logs
5) collect rather 1E+3 ~ 1E+4 sized populations of test-runs, not just a few units of individual trials

Given your solution is already implemented in both a pure-[SERIAL] code-execution fashion and in some other `[CONCURRENT]` or even `[PARALLEL]`, the most exact step is to compare the end-to-end test durations.

It is quite common to use monotonic-clocks, having better than `~ [us]` resolution in `[TIME]`-domain.

For more details about internalities, best view the **[re-formulated Amdahl's Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)** and the **criticism** of of the **parallel-speedup** initial, unconstrained-resources use formulation.